# Why does a link open in the new tab but not in the current tab?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

I have the following link on my page. The link points to an internal address.

```
<a href="internal_address"> Add XYZ and do ABC</a>
```

When I click on the link, nothing happens. The browser shows a loading icon, but stays on the current page. If I right click on the link and say open in new tab, the link open perfectly in the new tab. What is the reason for this? How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: What is `internal_address` really?

Comment: It is just a URL : http://internal.pvt.mydomain.com/xyz/abc?a=lmn&b=123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the target of the hyperlink element

```
<a href="internal_address" target="_blank"> Add XYZ and do ABC</a>
```

Another example (which if copied directly into a HTML file will work)

```
<a href="http:\\www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Goto Google</a>
```